# Wrong TSX ternary markup block formatting in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier, tsx

I like 'format on save' VSCode feature very much. But now I'm experiencing annoying wrong formatting of `tsx` files in VS Code (1.49.2).

Here is an example. Here two lines have extra indents ('single' block)

```
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = (props: { isList: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.isList ? (
        <div>liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiist</div>
      ) : (
          <div>siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiingle</div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

the same code in `jsx` file is formatted correctly

```
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.isList ? (
        <div>liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiist</div>
      ) : (
        <div>siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiingle</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

I tried to switch default vscode formatter to `eslint`, `null`, `prettier` (user/workspace) - no difference. When I run `prettier --write src/components/TestComponent.tsx` the tsx file is formatted correctly.
I also checked typescript-specific formatting settings in VS Code, but couldn't find anything related. For the test I've removed `.eslint.js` config file and my project doesn't have `.prettierrc` config.

Answer (score 1):

it was wrong formatter specified in `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json` (on **Linux**), something like

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
}
```

it should be either set to `esbenp.prettier-vscode` or removed in order to use the default one

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by going to my user settings and deleting

```
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
```

and configuring prettier to be the default formatter